# Getting Values from an Editable GridView and Using it as a Parameter for a SqlDataSource - BackEnd

Tags: c#, asp.net

Still a complete beginner with Asp.Net, and a google search didn't turn up the right results I have anticipated. I apologize if there is already a duplicate question.

The problem I have is that I have a editable gridview below:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCodes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="CodesDataSource" CellPadding="3" Width="474px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" OnRowDataBound="gvCodes_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Id"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Code"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Manager_Name" HeaderText="Manager Name" SortExpression="Manager_Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created_Date" HeaderText="Created Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Created_Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/d/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my SQLDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="CodesDataSource" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Codes] WHERE [Id] = @Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Codes] ([Manager_Name]) VALUES (@Manager_Name, @Created_Date)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Codes] WHERE [ProjProjectID] = 'DynamicValue'" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Codes] SET [Manager_Name] = @Manager_Name, [Created_Date] = GETDATE() WHERE [Id] = @Id AND [ProjProjectID] = 'DynamicValue'" OnSelected="CodesDataSource_Selected">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Manager_Name" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Created_Date"></asp:Parameter>
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Manager_Name" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Created_Date"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to be able to move the SqlDataSource all to BackEnd, at least the parameters so that I could change the projProjectID in the where. This is what I have tried:

```
projProjectID = Request.QueryString["ProjProjectID"].ToString();

        private void LoadSqlDataSource()
    {
        CodesDataSource.ConnectionString = ba.connection;
        CodesDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Codes WHERE ProjProjectID = '" + projProjectID + "'";
        CodesDataSource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Codes SET Manager_Name = @Manager_Name, Created_Date = GETDATE() WHERE Id = @Id AND ProjProjectID = '" + projProjectID + "'";

        //CodesDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("Manager_Name", TypeCode.String, ___);
        //CodesDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("Created_Date", TypeCode.String, ___);
        //CodesDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("Id", TypeCode.String, ___);
    }
```

The ____ is where the error occurs. It is expecting a string value. What I don't know how to do is get that specific value edited by the user in the gridview to go into that ___. I only need the Manager_Name to work.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event `gvCodes_RowUpdating`, handle the functionality of updating like this.

```
protected void gvCodes_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvCodes.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox textID = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
    TextBox textDate = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
    TextBox textManagerName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

    CodesDataSource.ConnectionString = ba.connection;
    CodesDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Codes WHERE ProjProjectID = '" + projProjectID + "'";
    CodesDataSource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Codes SET Manager_Name = @Manager_Name, Created_Date = GETDATE() WHERE Id = @Id AND ProjProjectID = '" + projProjectID + "'";

    CodesDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("Manager_Name", TypeCode.String, textManagerName.Text);
    CodesDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("Created_Date", TypeCode.String, textDate.Text);
    CodesDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("Id", TypeCode.String, textID.Text);
 }
```

Advice:
Using parameters helps prevent **SQL Injection attacks** and hence you should include all as parameters like `projProjectID` also. Also, You should use SqlCommand instead of SqlDataSource at the backend:

```
    string updateStatement = "UPDATE Codes SET Manager_Name = @Manager_Name, Created_Date = GETDATE() WHERE Id = @Id AND ProjProjectID = @projectID";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection))  {
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Manager_Name", textManagerName.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Created_Date", textDate.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", textID.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@projectID", projProjectID));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Richa! Answered my question and even gave me advice :)